# send HTML as attachment in email

Tags: php, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email with an HTML attachment,
I don't want the html to show in the message,
I actually want the file to be attached.

I'm half way there, I have the file attached in the email,
but hotmail is showing the html in the message aswell as attaching it.

I'm using the mime type: application/x-download but have also tried text/html, both have the same result.

Failing the answer to this question, it would be useful if someone knows a file type that can be opened on any computer (except pdf or images) where the source of the file can contain raw/uncompressed text. I'm basically emailing a voucher with the users details filled in onto the voucher, so I'm using `str_replace` to get them on there and so can't use a pdf with `str_replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the content-disposition to attachment then the MUA should not display the HTML until the user accesses it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already don't use PHPs `mail()` function directly. Use a wrapper class such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). They give you far more flexibility and are safer.

As far as generating the voucher I would be most tempted to generate an image with GD if they aren't able to just print the email. This way it will be possible for all users to open it. Some people may not have access to a PDF reader for example.

Is there any reason why they can't just print out the email as the voucher or that you can't just give them a unique voucher number that the can write down? This gives them the greatest flexibility because some customers will not have access to a printer.

Comment: I think I'll just stick with HTML for now, PDFs and GDs might be a bit overkill but thanks for the suggestion. As for unique voucher number, it's for a company in-house use, when users complete the quiz they get a free meal at the canteen so all users will have a printer, but yeah if it was for a website then good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PHP mail function, you will have to code the ENTIRE email by hand (headers, boundaries, ect) which is annoying and can be difficult to debug.

If you have PEAR installed, they make it extremely easy to do this with the [Pear Mail Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected) and [Pear Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) extensions.  They are very simple to use.

If you don't have PEAR installed, there are other wrappers you can use (mentioned in the post by Treffynnon).